# How can I make a precise one-way clutch using Technic elements?

Tags: nxt, building, technic, gears, mechanical

I need a mechanism so that if a (NXT) motor rotates forward, it moves one gear, but the other stays still, but if it rotates backwards, the first gear does not move, but the second one does.

I found an example solution for one half of the problem [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_IstqVQB8A) (I would need 2 of these), but that seems like it would take part of a rotation to pick up, and I need mine to be really precise.

I am building this for the Z-Axis/Extruder of the [NXTStrap](http://reprap.org/wiki/NXTStrap).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Would this solve your problem? Depending on the direction of the input, only one axle will turn.
[image: Depending on the direction of the input, only one axle will turn]

Comment: Does this solve @Ari Porad 's problem? The best resolution you could get with this device is 1/4 of a turn.

Comment: ^ Why would you say that? It's free to rotate as much as it wants, because the four-lobed "Gears" will simply slip underneath the angled stoppers, in one direction.

Comment: @RallyToMe, technically MindS1 is right, it could take as much as a quarter turn until the knob wheel gets locked. This can however be reduced by using ordinary gears, the more teeth the smaller the error at the price of increased size.